# Need help with converting Celsius to Fahrenheit in the code

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

I'm new to Arduino and trying to figure out how to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit with the parameters listed below. Do I need to create a separate file for the calculations? If so, can someone help me on how I can go about doing that?

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

int SENSOR = 2;
int TEMPERATURE;
int HUMIDITY;

DHT dht(SENSOR, DHT11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  TEMPERATURE = dht.readTemperature();
  HUMIDITY = dht.readHumidity();
  Serial.print("Temp: ");
  Serial.print(TEMPERATURE);
  Serial.println(" celsius ");
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.println(HUMIDITY);
  delay(2000);

  //Built In LED
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(250); // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(250);  
}
```

Comment: If dht.readTemperature() and dht.readHumidity() return floating point numbers then you may want to change TEMPERATURE and HUMIDITY to "float" instead of "int".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Adafruit DHT sensor library, then you can get a
Fahrenheit reading by passing `true` as an argument to
`readTemperature()`. C.f. [the comment in the source code](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/1.3.0/DHT.cpp#L34). For
example:

```c++
Serial.print("Temp: ");
Serial.print(dht.readTemperature(true));  // true -> Fahrenheit
Serial.println(" deg. F");
```

Note that this library offers also the conversion functions
`convertCtoF()` and `convertFtoC()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function to your sketch.

```
// Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion
double Fahrenheit(double celsius){
  return 1.8 * celsius + 32;
}
```

Then add this code to your loop().

```
Serial.print("Temp: ");
Serial.print(Fahrenheit(TEMPERATURE));
Serial.println(" fahrenheit ");
```